# Is '#include "file2.c"' different from 'gcc file1.c file2.c'?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, linker

Is there any reason to prefer linker commands over include directives **if** you don't plan on recompiling the included files separately?

P.S. If it matters, I'm actually concerned with C++ and g++, but I thought gcc would be more recognizable as a generic compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any reason to prefer linker commands over include directives

Yes. You'll get into serious trouble if you include implementation (`.c`) files here and there. Meet the infamous "Multiple definitions of symbol _MyFunc" linker error...

(By the way, it's also considered bad style/practice, in general, only header files are meant to be included.)

Comment: @CoryNelson yes, and that causes even more confusion, for example if you have two identically named static function...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to just have one long C file, use your editor to insert file2.c into file1.c and then delete file2.c. If they ALWAYS go together, then that's (possibly) the right solution. Using #include for this is not the right solution.

The reason we split files into separate .c anc .cpp files is that they logically do something separate from the rest of the code. Compiling each unit separately is a good idea when programs are large, but the main reason for splitting things into separate files is to show the independence of each unit of code. This way, you can see what other parts affect this particular file (looking at the headers that are included). If a class is local to a .cpp file, you know that class isn't used somewhere else in the system, so you can safely change the internals of that class without having to worry about other components being affected, for example. On the other hand, if everything is in one large file, then it's very hard to follow what's affecting what, and what is safe to change.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the difference. `file1.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int foo = 37;
int main() { printf("%d\n", foo); }
```

`file2.c`:

```
static int foo = 42;
```

These two trivial modules compile fine with `gcc file1.c file2.c`, even though `file2.c`'s definition of `foo` is then never used. `static` identifiers are visible only within a translation unit (C's version of what is more commonly called a module).

When you `#include "file2.c"` in `file1.c`, you effectively insert `file2.c` into `file1.c`, causing an identifier clash before the two files now become one translation unit.

As a rule, never `#include` a C or C++ source file. Only `#include` headers.